# What's the alternative to GridJexlPredicate2 in GridGain 6 (open source version)

Tags: grid-computing, gridgain

We're migrating an application from an older gridgain 4 codebase to gridgain 6. In the old application, we used a GridJexlPredicate2 to tie into a monitor method that determined if a node should run a particular job (basically, checked if node contained a particular attribute value).

In gridgain 6, I suspect we should be using the GridBiPredicate class. However, is there a replacement for the expression language based GridJexlPredicate2 class or is there a different programatic / declarative approach I should be looking at?

Thanks

```
/**
* Creates the topology filter used to select nodes for processing.
* The expression string will have three variables that can be referenced:
* <dl>
* <dt><strong>node</strong></dt>
* <dd>The GridNode being tested</dd>
* <dt><strong>session</strong></dt>
* <dd>The GridTaskSession for the task being executed</dd>
* <dt><strong>monitor</strong></dt>
* <dd>The GridNodeMonitor monitoring nodes on the grid</dd>
* </dl>
*
* @param monitor The monitor instance to be bound into the expression
*context for use in the filter expression
* @return A {@link GridBiPredicate} used to filter nodes
*/
  public static GridJexlPredicate2<GridNode, GridComputeTaskSession>    createTopologyFilter(GridNodeMonitor monitor) {
    GridJexlPredicate2<GridNode, GridComputeTaskSession> filter = new GridJexlPredicate2<GridNode, GridComputeTaskSession>("monitor.canAcceptJobs(node)","node", "session");
    return filter.with("monitor", monitor);
}
```

Comment: BTW, One solution would be to clone the GridJexlPredicate2 from the old GridGain source, . but is that the right approach?

Comment: You can do it, but I am not sure for what benefit. The new way seems cleaner to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternative is to use GridProjection with a filter

```
final MyNodeMonitor monitor = ...;

Grid grid = GridGain.gridI();

GridProjection prj = grid.forPredicate(new GridPredicate<GridNode>() {
    @Override public boolean apply(GridNode node) {
        return monitor.canAcceptJobs(node);
    }
});

GridComputeTaskFuture<?> fut = prj.compute().execute(new MyTask());

// Synchronous wait.
fut.get();
```

Comment: Yes, that should work. However, is there a configuration based option, In GridGain 4, we did something like this:

Comment: The configuration bean could be set up with filtering predicates.  If that's no longer an option, what is the best solution (we have several tasks and jobs) `bean id="abstractGridConfiguration" abstract="true" class="org.gridgain.grid.GridConfiguration">
.
.
 <property name="topologySpi">
  <bean class="org.gridgain.grid.spi.topology.nodefilter.GridNodeFilterTopologySpi">
   <property name="filter">
  <bean class="com.interlegis.enterprise.gridgain.license.GridNodeMonitorImpl" factory-method="createTopologyFilter">
   <constructor-arg ref="gridNodeMonitor"/>
  </bean>
 </property>
.
.
</bean>`

Comment: @VinayB The Topology SPI has been removed from the product, so there is no longer a way to do it as you are suggesting. The new way seems cleaner though.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I'll revisit our code with your comments in mind